# How to remove a carriage return from a string

Tags: java, regex, carriage-return

```
String s ="SSR/DANGEROUS GOODS AS PER ATTACHED SHIPPERS
/DECLARATION 1 PACKAGE

NFY
/ACME CONSOLIDATORS"
```

How to strip the space between "PACKAGE" and "NFY" ?

Comment: This is the corrent answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171852/java-replaceall-doesnt-work-well-with-backslash

Answer (score 44):

Java's `String.replaceAll` in fact takes a regular expression. You could remove all newlines with:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\n", "");
s = s.replaceAll("\\r", "");
```

But this will remove *all* newlines.

Note the double `\`'s: so that the string that is passed to the regular expression parser is `\n`.

You can also do this, which is smarter:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");
```

This would remove all sequences of 2 or more whitespaces, replacing them with a single space. Since newlines are also whitespaces, it should do the trick for you.

Comment: Also, `s.replaceAll("(?:\\n|\\r)", "");` achieves the same in a single statement. And one can tailor the expression to be more selective.

Comment: You can *always* match text that has newlines in it; you don't need a flag for that.  What MULTILINE does is change the meaning of the anchors, `^` and `$`, allowing them to match at line boundaries as well as the beginning and end of the whole string.  Since there are no anchors in your regex, the MULTILINE flag has no effect.

Comment: You're right - just tried it with the `Pattern.MULTILINE` commented out. But (what I had tried originally) `s = s.replace("\\s{2,}", " ");` doesn't work. It doesn't remove the newlines. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry - just realized I'm using `replace`, not `replaceAll`. Stupid!

Answer (score 2):

```
s = s.replaceAll("[\\n\\r]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
s = s.replaceAll( "PACKAGE\\s*NFY", "PACKAGE NFY" );
```

Comment: +0 This is not generalized enough to be helpful to others.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a replace function? Something in the lines of:

```
youString.Replace("\r", "")
```

Answer (score -3):

```
string = string.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
```

Comment: Come on, the question is tagged `java`. Can't you give a solution in `Java`?